# How to interpret Solr Admin Analysis screen

Tags: apache, solr, query-analyzer

I'm reading the docs on the analyzer screen of the Solr Admin, but I'm still not sure how to determine when a given query matches with something-- is this when it is shaded light blue after a step in its analyzer chain? Also is there a way to see how many it matches on and what words they are specifically?

Finally, what is the difference between typing a query into Field Value (Index) and Field Value (Query)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case could be helpful to post a screenshot of what you're seeing. The panel is split in two sections, the left (field value) simulates the value that would be indexed when you add a document, and the panel on the right simulates the values that will be sent through the query analysis chain. This is designed like this because you ca have different configurations for the index/query in your FieldType.

Yes, the values that match are highlighted with the light blue, also is highlighted multiple times because it starts the first time that the token matched, so if you defined different filters on your FieldType you'll get one row of tokens (token stream) after it goes through that transformation.

If multiple tokens/terms from your query match the field values, then all those terms that matched will be highlighted.

Keep in mind that this is not firing a normal search query to Solr (so you're not searching documents), is just sending what you put on the left and on the right (field value, and query) through the FieldType analysis chain selected (FieldType) and showing what you'll get out (tokens/terms).

[image: solr analysis]

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm also wondering about the last part of what you said-- since this isn't firing a normal search query to Solr, how does this compare? More specifically, in the Analyzer I specify a fieldType which then dictates which analysis chain to go through on the text, but when I do a general search what is happening? Does it do this analysis chain for all fieldTypes and look for matches in all of them? If this is the case, is there an order of importance among results? Thanks so much!

Comment: What I meant with the "this is not searching" is just means that it uses the same analysis chains that you defined in your `schema.xml` but it's not firing a query against the inverted index, so is not *really searching* is showing you how the text is going to be treated when you do a search query or when you send documents into solr, look at it as a simulation, so you don't have access to scoring in this view or result ordering because it is not really executing the search, and yes this process is executed per field/fieldType.